# PySide 1.2.2 installation on Redhat Linux

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

Trying to install PySide 1.2.2 as below.

```
[ananthul@ homes/PySide-1.2.2]$python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 25 2014, 14:10:55) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import platform
>>> platform.architecture()[0]
'64bit'
```

Command for installation is below

```
python setup.py install
[ananthul@xxxxx homes/PySide-1.2.2]$qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
```

When I tried above command , I got installation error below.

```
Linking CXX shared library libshiboken-python2.7.so
/usr/bin/ld: Python-2.7.6/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o):relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
Python-2.7.6/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libshiboken/libshiboken-python2.7.so.1.2.2] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libshiboken/CMakeFiles/libshiboken.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Tried compiling python with --enable-shared option while doing ./configure . This solved the problem.